# What is the reason for TypeError: 'Zero' object has no attribute '__getitem__'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, typeerror, zero

I have written the following code in python 2.7 in order to calculate an integration numerically and then use the result of this integration for further steps of the project.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linspace,logspace
from cosmicpy import *



Omega_Matter, Omega_DarkEnergy, A, b, rho_critical, m = 0.306, 0.694, 0.3222, 0.707, 2.77536627e+11, 1000000

def D(z):
    a = 1/(1+z)
    x = (Omega_DarkEnergy/Omega_Matter)**(1/3)*a
    return (5/2)*(Omega_Matter/Omega_DarkEnergy)**(1/3)*x**(-3/2)*(1+x**3)**(1/2)* \
           (x**2/(3*x**3 + 3) - np.log(x + 1)/9 + np.log(x**2 - x + 1)/18 \
                          + np.sqrt(3)*np.arctan(2*np.sqrt(3)*x/3 \
                  - np.sqrt(3)/3)/9 + np.sqrt(3)*np.pi/54)     

def delta(z): 
    return D(z)/D(0) 
def W(k, M):
    rho_m = rho_critical*Omega_Matter
    R = (3*M/(4*np.pi*rho_m))**(1/3)
    x = k*R
    return (3/x)*(sin(x)-x*cos(x))

my_cosmology = cosmology(Omega_m=0.306, Omega_de=0.694, h=0.679, Omega_b=0.0483, n=0.968, tau=0.067, sigma8=0.815, w=-1)
k_array = np.logspace(-16,4,m)
P = my_cosmology.pk_lin(k_array)

def sigma_squared(z, M):
    dk = (np.max(k_array)-np.min(k_array))/(m-1)
    summation = []
    for k in k_array:
        Integral = 0
        Integrand = k**2*P[k]*(W(k, M))**2
        Integral += dk * np.sum(Integrand[k])  
    summation.append(Integral)  
    return ((delta(z))**2/(2*(np.pi)**2))*summation[-1]
    print(summation)  


sigma_squared(0.01, 1e+9)
```

As I write more of the code, I check my steps one by one by getting a print and see if the output is what I expect. However, I am unable to produce the final product of the last function which is supposed to be a value given the values for the variables z and M. In particular I am sure that something is wrong with the integration inside that function because I am not getting any thing for `print(summation)` which is supposed to be a big 1d array whose last element `print(summation[-1])`should give me the area under the curve (upto a pre-factor defined in the final return of the function). Here is the error message and I couldn't find any on-line source for the particular error message I am getting. Your help is greatly appreciated.

> mycode.py:95: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number
>   instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
>   Integrand = k**2*P[k]*(W(k, M))**2 Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File "mycode.py", line 102, in 
>       sigma_squared(0.01, 1e+9)   File "mycode.py", line 96, in sigma_squared
>       Integral += dk * np.sum(Integrand[k])   TypeError: 'Zero' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

---

Edited Code (which is too slow to know if it is working correctly):

```
k_array = np.logspace(-16,4,m)
my_cosmology = cosmology(Omega_m=0.306, Omega_de=0.694, h=0.679, Omega_b=0.0483, n=0.968, tau=0.067, sigma8=0.815, w=-1)
P = my_cosmology.pk_lin(k_array)
M_array = np.logspace(8,16,n)

def W(k, M):
    rho_m = rho_critical*Omega_Matter
    R = (3*M/(4*np.pi*rho_m))**(1/3)
    y = k*R
    return (3/y**3)*(sin(y)-y*cos(y))


def sigma_squared(z, M):
    dk = (np.max(k_array)-np.min(k_array))/(m-1)
    summation = []
    for k in k_array:
        for M in M_array:
            Integral = 0
            Integrand = k**2*P[k]*(W(k, M))**2
            Integral += dk * np.sum(Integrand)
    summation.append(Integral)  
    return ((delta(z))**2/(2*(np.pi)**2))*summation[-1]


print(sigma_squared(0, 1e+9))
```

Comment: The text of the error let think that at that moment, `P` is not what you expect. You could try to print it before entering the function, of use a try except block to print it when the exception is risen

Comment: `Integrand` is an integer not an array, so `Integrand[k]` is a syntax error in python.

Comment: I changed the code as you see, but now it runs forever. I am not sure how to speed it up.